# Python pandas replace the values of a DataFrame by searching in another DataFrame with non-identical labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, series

I have two dataframes.
**df1** contains CITIES and the total number of VISITS.
**df2** contains the VISITS records.

Periodically **df1** is updated with the data from **df2** with the new VISITS.

**df1** example (before updating)

```
ID    NAME     VISITS
---
01    CITY1    01
02    CITY2    01
...
06    CITYZ    12
```

**df2** example

```
CITY     NUMBER
---
...
CITY1    01
CITY2    01    <--- highest of CITY2
CITYZ    13
CITY1    02
...
CITYZ    14
CITY1    03    <--- highest of CITY1
CITYZ    15    <--- highest of CITYZ
```

To update it will look for **df1**['NAME'] in **df2**['CITY'] (this is the correlation) and take the highest **df2**['NUMBER'] and put it in **df1**['VISITS'] of that CITY.

**df1** after updating

```
ID    NAME     VISITS
---
01    CITY1    03    <--- updated
02    CITY2    01    <--- updated or not, it doesn't matter
...
06    CITYZ    15    <--- updated
```

my approach:

```
df2.loc[df2['CITY'] == 'CITYZ', 'NUMBER'].max()
```

I get the max number of "CITIZ" (hardcoded), but I don't know how to link it to **df1**.

The next is clearly wrong, but it is the idea:

```
df1['VISITS'] = df2.loc[df2['CITY'] == df1['NAME'], 'NUMBER'].max()
```

This "solution" gives the following error: **ValueError**: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove duplicates from `df2` and keep only the last updated values (if your cities are already sorted by 'NUMBER', you can remove `sort_values`):

```
df1['VISITS'] = df1['NAME'].map(df2.sort_values('NUMBER', ascending=True)
                                   .drop_duplicates('CITY', keep='last')
                                   .set_index('CITY')['NUMBER'])
print(df1)

# Output
   ID   NAME  VISITS
0   1  CITY1       3
1   2  CITY2       1
2   6  CITYZ      15
```

Based on @Nick's answer:

```
df1['VISITS'] = df1['NAME'].map(df2.groupby('CITY')['NUMBER'].max())
```

Input data:

```
>>> df1
   ID   NAME  VISITS
0   1  CITY1       1
1   2  CITY2       1
2   6  CITYZ      12

>>> df2
    CITY  NUMBER
0  CITY1       1
1  CITY2       1
2  CITYZ      13
3  CITY1       2
4  CITYZ      14
5  CITY1       3
6  CITYZ      15
```

Comment: You can also use the `groupby.idxmax` approach ;)

Comment: I love your adaptation of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to drop the `VISITS` column from `df1`, then `join` that to `df2` grouped by `CITY` and aggregated as `max`, renaming the `NUMBER` column to `VISITS`:

```
out = (df1
       .drop('VISITS', axis=1)
       .set_index('NAME')
       .join(df2.groupby('CITY')['NUMBER'].max())
       .rename(columns={'NUMBER':'VISITS'})
       .reset_index()
      )
```

Output for your sample data:

```
    NAME  ID  VISITS
0  CITY1   1       3
1  CITY2   2       1
2  CITYZ   6      15
```